# Where do you set the task_id of a celery task?

Tags: python, django-celery, celery-task

I am having trouble finding any example of setting a task_id with my own task_id

something along these lines...

```
def testview1(request):
    for i in xrange(0,1000):
        result = add.delay( i, 4,task_id = i)
        print result.info
        #value = result.wait()
    return HttpResponse("Done") 


@task()
def add(task_id, x, y):
    print add.task_id
    print str(x+y)
    return x + y
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

delay doesn't support options, it's a shortcut to apply_async:

```
add.apply_async(args, kwargs, task_id=i)

add.apply_async((1, 4), task_id=i)
```

Also the id of the current task is in `task.request.id` not `task.id` like you have above.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question you may be able to help me with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238477/mopping-up-after-celery-results-when-stored-in-db

Comment: This is super handy!