# Where does Django-celery/RabbitMQ store task results? 

Tags: django, celery

My celery database backend settings are:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"
CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "mysqlite.db"
```

I am using RabbitMQ as my messager.

It doesn't seem like any results are getting stored in the db, and yet I can read the results after the task is complete. Are they in memory or a RabbitMQ cache?

I haven't tried reading the same result multiple times, so maybe its a read once then poof!

Comment: actually it seems that the sqlite db is growing in size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CELERY_RESULT_DBURI is for the sqlalchemy result backend, not the Django one.
The Django one always uses the default database configured in the DATABASES setting (or the DATABASE_* settings if on older Django versions)

Comment: ok. So what do you do with the results as they pile up in the django db? I can't seem to find an example of interacting with the results in an ORM way.

Answer (score 0):

my celery daemons work just fine, but I'm having difficulties with collecting task results. task_result.get() leads a timeout. and task.state is always PENDING..(but jobs are completed) i tried separate sqlite dbs, a single postgres db shared by workers. but i still cant get results. CELERY_RESULT_DBURI seems useless to me (for celery 2.5 )i think it's a newer configuration. Any suggestions are welcomed...

---

EDIT: it's all my fault:
i give extra parameters to my tasks with decorators, **ignore_results=True** Parameter create this problem. I deleted this key and it works like a charm :)